# Проблема с форматом даты SQL SERVER (приоритеты типов данных)

Tags: c#, sql-server

На клиенте вызываю процедуру, которая по передаваемому флагу возвращает либо

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE
             WHEN a.datprihod IS NULL
             THEN CASE
                  WHEN a.srok = 5
                  THEN b.fprminpricedue
                  WHEN a.srok = 6
                  THEN b.fprminduepricedue
                  WHEN a.srok = 7
                  THEN b.fprminpriceduewithdue
                  WHEN a.srok = 1
                  THEN RTRIM(CONVERT( NCHAR, GETDATE(), 104))
                  ELSE 'нет информации'
                  END
             ELSE RTRIM(CONVERT(NCHAR, a.datprihod, 104))
             END
```

, либо

```
SELECT ISNULL(sbd.ItemName,
                          (
                              SELECT Name
                              FROM dbo.pct_ItemType
                              WHERE pkid = sbd.IDItem
                          )),
                    RTRIM(CAST(dbo.ufn_sls_GetBillDetRubItemPrice(sbd.PKID) AS  NCHAR))+N'₽',
                    CAST(sbd.Quantity AS   NCHAR),
                    RTRIM(CAST(dbo.ufn_sls_GetBillDetRubItemPrice(sbd.PKID)*sbd.Quantity AS  NCHAR))+N'₽',
                    ISNULL(sbd.status,
                               CASE
                                   WHEN sbd.datprihod IS NULL
                                   THEN CASE
                                            WHEN sbd.srok = 5
                                            THEN b.fprminpricedue
                                            WHEN sbd.srok = 6
                                            THEN b.fprminduepricedue
                                            WHEN sbd.srok = 7
                                            THEN b.fprminpriceduewithdue
                                            WHEN sbd.srok = 1
                                            THEN RTRIM(CONVERT( NCHAR, GETDATE(), 104))
                                            ELSE 'нет информации'
                                        END
                                   ELSE RTRIM(CONVERT( NCHAR, sbd.datprihod, 104))
                               END)
```

Ожидаю получить `22.08.2016`.

**Первый случай**:
получаю `22.08.2016 00:00:00`

**Второй случай**:
получаю `2016-08-22`

Такие разные результаты получаю для одного и того же клиента.

Обработка на клиенте такая:

```
using (var items = await comm.ExecuteReaderAsync())
     {
        while (await items.ReadAsync())
            {
               Console.Write($"Наименование - {items[0]}, \nДата - {items[1]}");    
            }    
     }
```

Пробовал явное приведение в виде

```
{((DateTime)items[1]).ToShortDateString()}
```

Это работает, но если возвращается `'нет информации'`, то всё, конечно, падает.

Comment: @nick, задача получить значение `DateColumn`, а если там пусто, то текущую дату. Текст возвращается, если не выполнено ещё одно условие, которое я не стал приводить в коде.

Comment: @nick, `items[1].ToString` излишнее действие, ибо оно выполняется и так, под капотом. А вообще это же `object`. Результаты такие получаются на одном клиенте, обновил описание задачи.

Comment: @nick, про второй `ISNULL` написал выше. Там есть ещё условия. Уберу из описания задачи, чтоб не смущать остальных.

Comment: а если так указать? items[1].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: А может дата через **'-'** у вас выплывает из куска **'Some text'** где те условия, которые вы неопубликовали?

Comment: Обновил описание

Comment: Тогда понятно, у вас как минимум `THEN CASE
                  WHEN a.srok = 5
                  THEN b.fprminpricedue` не обвёрнуто в convert - вот и случай с `-` вам нужно все даты обвернуть. Я вам могу упростить

Comment: @nick, нет, возвращается именно по условию `a.srok = 1` в обоих случаях.

Comment: Вот не надо выводить строки вроде "нет информации"! Использовали бы лучше NULL, а всякие "нет информации" подставляли уже на клиенте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, проблема была в том, что я не знал о [приоритете типов данных SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190309.aspx).

> Если оператор связывает два выражения различных типов данных, то по правилам приоритета типов данных определяется, какой тип данных имеет меньший приоритет и будет преобразован в тип данных с большим приоритетом. Если неявное преобразование не поддерживается, возвращается ошибка. Если оба операнда выражения имеют одинаковый тип данных, результат операции будет иметь тот же тип данных.

У типов `NCHAR`, `CHAR`, `NVARCHAR` и `VARCHAR` приоритет ниже, чем у `DATE` и `DATETIME`, что, соответственно, и приводит к таким результатам, которые меня смутили.

Решение заключается в приведении типов возвращаемых значений всех веток выражения `CASE` к типу данных, имеющему наиболее низкий приоритет из используемых в выражении.

**Пример**
Запрос

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN 1 > 0
           THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 104)
           ELSE CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
       END;
```

вернёт `2016-08-23`. А если убрать второе условие

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN 1 > 0
       THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 104)
       -- ELSE CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
   END;
```

или привести тип его возвращаемого значения к типу с более низким приоритетом (не обязательно даже к `CHAR`)

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN 1 > 0
       THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 104)
       ELSE CONVERT(BINARY, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
   END;
```

то получим то, что хотим - `23.08.2016`.

Answer (score 1):

В первом выражении

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE
             WHEN a.datprihod IS NULL
             THEN CASE
                  WHEN a.srok = 5
                  THEN b.fprminpricedue --**
                  WHEN a.srok = 6
                  THEN b.fprminduepricedue --**
                  WHEN a.srok = 7
                  THEN b.fprminpriceduewithdue --**
                  WHEN a.srok = 1
                  THEN RTRIM(CONVERT( NCHAR, GETDATE(), 104))
                  ELSE 'нет информации'
                  END
             ELSE RTRIM(CONVERT(NCHAR, a.datprihod, 104))
             END
```

у вас не всё обвёрнуто в convert (выделил жирным),  поэтому у вас и выдаёт на эти случаи `"-"`
Я бы первую часть сделал бы так. Может вам пригодится coalesce, она работает как isnull но на два-три-и более параметров.

```
select top 1 isnull(cast(convert(char(10), isnull(a.datprihod, 
CASE WHEN a.srok = 5 THEN b.fprminpricedue
WHEN a.srok = 6
                  THEN b.fprminduepricedue
                  WHEN a.srok = 7
                  THEN b.fprminpriceduewithdue
                  WHEN a.srok = 1
then getdate() end) , 104 ) as varchar(20)),'нет информации');
```

Тут забыл указать ещё одну особенность. В mssql первым берётся тот тип, который указан первым. В вашем выражении 'CASE       WHEN a.datprihod IS NULL
                 THEN CASE
                      WHEN a.srok = 5
                      THEN b.fprminpricedue ' первая переменная **fprminpricedue** имеет тип datetime, именно поэтому вне зависимости от a.srok даже при a.srok=1 дата приводится к datetime стандарту с "-", тоесть после convert она всёравно конвентируется назад в datetime а константа вообще даст исключение.

Comment: Я уже писал, что срабатывает условие `a.srok = 1` в обоих случаях, это 100%. К тому же конверт `'нет информации'` в `char(10)` не годится.

Comment: Кажется разобрался - если закомментировать все остальные условия, кроме `a.srok = 1`, то дата приходит в нормальном виде. Очевидно, это особенность `CASE` в типах возвращаемых значений.

Comment: Если сделать приведение для всех условий, как вы и советовали для приличия, то тоже всё корректно работает.

Comment: Мой код таки режет текст, поправил. char(10) с convert выбрасывает время. Хорошо. Я поставил обработчик даты один на все даты. А обработчик текста вконец. Пробуйте. Значит выходит у вас возвращается одна из дат которая не приведена к нормальному стандарту.

Comment: спасибо, я уже решил проблему конвертами. Теперь вопрос в другом - особенности типов возвращаемых значений в `CASE`.

Comment: Я поправил выражение. Там особенность, что какой тип sql встретил первым - тот и главный. напрмер `select coalsesce(cast(null as varchar(20)), convert(isnull(...,getdate()),104),'нет данных')` даст тоже правильный ответ.