# Case When условие в then

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть  2 таблицы
`dbo.Application`:

```
| id | RealResID |
+----+-----------+
|337 | 4         |   

dbo.Resolutions

| id   | AppID | ResID | date       | CreatedAt  |
+------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
| 114  | 337   | 2     | null       | 2016-12-12 |
| 257  | 337   | 3     | 2016-10-27 | 2016-12-12 |
| 300  | 337   | 4     | 2016-11-01 | 2016-12-12 |
```

Нужно выбрать дату если `ResID` = 4 то выбрать дату не по своей а `2016-10-27`(`ResID = 3`)
А остальных случаях выбрать дату по своей(если
`ResID`= 2 то `null`, `ResID` = 3 то `2016-10-27`)
Мой запрос:

```
select id,
case when ResID = 3 then date
case when ResID = 4 then 
                        (case when ResID = 3 then date)
else createdAt
from dbo.Application a
left join Resolutions r on a.id = r.appID and r.ResID = a.RealResID
```

Comment: конструкция `case   when ...  then    [else] end` !  Вот  `select id, case when ResID = 4 then cast(   '2016-10-27' as date )  else  date end from dbo.Application` ну и особенность, тип в case when должен быть *одинаковый*. Ну зайдите на msdn на сайт мелкософта, там всё красиво с примерами.

Comment: Очень похожий вопрос уже был на SO http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/557974/17974

Comment: Добавлю, не должен быть, а желательно, mssql приводит оба ответа из case when к тому типу который первый. Если выражение после then будет строка, то после else конвертирует в строку. Поэтому поставил cast, но можно без cast  `select id, case when ResID <> 4 then  date else '2016-10-27' end from dbo.Application`  либо параметр `?` или `@date` вместо константы.

Comment: Совершенно невменяемое описание... но из того, что удаётся додумать - нужно использовать вторую копию таблицы, чтобы брать данные из неё, если условие подмены истинно.

Answer (score 1):

Опишите вменяемо что вы хотите получить.

Но попробуйте такой запрос:

```
select src.id,
  case src.ResId
    when 3 then src.date
    when 4 then repl.date
    else src.CreatedAt
  end as VeryCoolDate
from dbo.Application src
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Application repl ON src.ResId = repl.id
```

Зависимый подзапрос в конструкции CASE не очень хорошо использовать по разным причинам, но тоже можно:

```
select id,
  case ResId
    when 3 then date
    when 4 then (
        select date 
        from dbo.Application repl 
        where src.ResId = repl.id
      )
    else CreatedAt
  end as VeryCoolDate
from dbo.Application src
```